# CakePHP: beforeSave not working with saveMany?

Tags: cakephp, save

So, for some reason, anything I do to data in the beforeSave callback, though it works on single records, does not work when using saveMany.

What gives? If I do the following:

```
public function beforeSave() {
    $this->data['foo'] = 'bar'
    die($this->data);
}
```

I can see that in fact $this->data does DOES get changed, but saveMany just ignores it and saves the original data instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you include the model name when manipulating $this->data, e.g. $this->data['Event']['foo'] = bar. Be sure the method returns true as well or the save will fail.

---

**Edit**

I whipped up a quick example and it seems to be working for me, see the code below. My suspicion is that maybe you are calling saveMany incorrectly and passing it the whole $this->request->data object but it's hard to guess without seeing your call as well.

**View**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ParentTable'); ?>
    Record 1: <br />
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('ParentTable.0.name'); ?>

    Record 2: <br />
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('ParentTable.1.name'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit'); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
    if ($this->request->data) {
        $this->ParentTable->saveMany($this->request->data['ParentTable']);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function beforeSave() {
    $this->data['ParentTable']['name'] .= ' modified';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm returning true. One problem is that saveMany uses just a numerical index so the format of the data is different than a regular save.

Comment: @BenjaminAllison did you try the code above or get it working?

Comment: Beauty! Works! Thank you Hoff! One thing that wasn't clear, and I just went on a hunch: beforeSave works on each records individually. So when using a saveMany, it treats each record, one at a time... unlike the afterFind callback, which will let one loop over an array when multiple records are returned. Heh!